# How to find the largest value of a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a forum application.  I have a script that creates a board.  In addition to the autoincremented board_id column, all boards have an integer column called position that is used to order the boards on the home page. When a new board is created, I want the default position to be the largest value within the rows of the boards table with the given category_id.  Positions can have duplicates because they are positioned within their category.  I hope that makes sense.

So if I have the following boards...

```
b_id | c_id | pos |
-------------------
  1  |   1  |  1  |
-------------------
  2  |   1  |  2  |
-------------------
  3  |   2  |  1  |
-------------------
```

And I am creating a new board in c_id 2, the position should be 2.  If the new board is in c_id 1, the position would be 3.  How can I do this?

The query below is what I am currently using, but the position always ends up being 0.

```
INSERT INTO `forum_boards` (
    `title`, 
    `description`, 
    `category_id`, 
    `position` 
) VALUES  (
    'Suggestion Box', 
     'Have an idea that will help us run things better? Let us know!',
     '1', 
    '(SELECT MAX(position), category_id FROM forum_boards WHERE category_id = 1)+1'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the approach you are using.  You need to drop the single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `forum_boards` (`title`,  `description`, `category_id`, `position` 
                           )
    VALUES  ('Suggestion Box', 
             'Have an idea that will help us run things better? Let us know!',
             1, 
             (SELECT MAX(position) + 1 FROM forum_boards WHERE category_id = 1)'
             );
```

However, this doesn't take into account categories that are initially empty.  And, I would write this using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO `forum_boards` (`title`,  `description`, `category_id`, `position` 
                           )
    SELECT 'Suggestion Box', 
           'Have an idea that will help us run things better? Let us know!',
           1, 
           COALESCE(MAX(position) + 1, 1)
    FROM forum_boards
    WHERE category_id = 1;
```

Note that I dropped the single quotes around `'1'`.  Numbers should be passed in as numbers, not strings.

Comment: With the first approach, if a category is empty, what would happen? would the select command return 0?

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 . . . The first approach will return `NULL`.  That is the code you were using.  The second returns `1` in that case.